# Input From Single User on Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to be able to obtain the response from a user. The problem is that I don’t know how to make sure that I get a specific user’s response and not somebody else’s. How would I be able to do this?
For example ask for minimum and maximum numbers and then get a random number from between them.

Here's what I've tried:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');


const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '-';

client.on('message', message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();


if(command === random) {
    message.channel.send('Please enter your starting number')
    channel.fetchMessages({ limit: 1 }).then(messages => {
        let min = messages.first();
    })
    message.channel.send('Please enter your limit')
    channel.fetchMessages({ limit: 1 }).then(messages => {
        let max = messages.first();
    })

    getRndInteger(min,max)

    function getRndInteger(min, max) {
        console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min); 
      }

    
}

});
```

I want it to wait until the user who activated it says a number (it could also have a timeout).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Channel.createMessageCollector()` to wait until your target user has replied, here's a quick example:

```js
let min, max;
const filter = (msg) => msg.author.id === message.author.id; // only match messages from whoever sent the command
const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { max: 2 });
collector.on("collect", (m) => {
  if(!min) { // if min hasn't already been set, set it
    min = parseInt(m.content);
  } else { // otherwise set max
    max = parseInt(m.content);
  }
});
collector.on("end", () => {
  getRndInteger(min, max);
});
```

There are other ways to go about this but I believe this is the most straightforward because you would need multiple listeners otherwise.

Comment: Its saying ` ReferenceError: getRndInteger is not defined`

Comment: Hi, this is caused by attempting to use `getRndInteger()` before you define it. To solve this, you must put `function getRndInteger(min, max) { ... }` somewhere before you call it. It'd be best to define the function outside of your message listener.